# Switching some text labels when the first image of a carousel is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there any way I can simplify this inefficient piece of JavaScript?

```
$(function () {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel');
    var $switch = $('#switch');
    var $header = $('#header');
    var $submit = $('#submit');

    $carousel.bind('slid', function() {
        var index = $('#carousel .item').index($('#carousel .carousel-inner .active'));
        if (index == 0) {
            $header.text('Sign In');
            $switch.text('Sign Up');
            $submit.text('Sign In');
            $submit.attr('form', 'sign_in');
        } else {
            $header.text('Sign Up');
            $switch.text('Sign In');
            $submit.text('Sign Up');
            $submit.attr('form', 'sign_up');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming `$` stands for `jQuery`?

Comment: @JanDvorak yea it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(function () {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel');
    var $switch = $('#switch');
    var $headerSubmit = $('#header, #submit');
    var $submit = $('#submit');
    var text_strings = [ 'Sign In', 'Sign Up' ];
    var form_strings = [ 'sign_in', 'sign_up' ];

    $carousel.bind('slid', function() {
        var index = $('#carousel .item').index($('#carousel .carousel-inner .active'));
        var sign_in = (index == 0);
        $headerSubmit.text(text_strings[sign_in ? 1 : 0]);
        $switch.text(text_strings[sign_in ? 0 : 1]);
        $submit.attr('form', form_strings[sign_in ? 1 : 0]);
    });
});
```

If you want to reduce the lines of code (with a slight *negative* impact to performance if this function gets called a lot), you could do this:

```
$(function () {
    var text_strings = [ 'Sign In', 'Sign Up' ];
    var form_strings = [ 'sign_in', 'sign_up' ];

    $('#carousel').bind('slid', function() {
        var index = $('#carousel .item').index($('#carousel .carousel-inner .active'));
        var sign_in = (index == 0);
        $('#header, #submit').text(text_strings[sign_in ? 1 : 0]);
        $('#switch').text(text_strings[sign_in ? 0 : 1]);
        $('#submit').attr('form', form_strings[sign_in ? 1 : 0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hm, i never thought about doing it like the last example you wrote, you said this will make the performance better?

Comment: I would use `+sign_in` instead of `sign_in?1:0` and `+!sign_in` instead of `sign_in?0:1`

Comment: @CristianRivera Sorry, I should've been more clear. It makes performance slightly worse since you call `$` every time the event executes.

Comment: @JanDvorak good point. Personally I don't like that trick; I feel it harms readability.

Comment: In the code above to counteract the calling of $ every time, can you load them into a var such as var $switch = $('#switch'); then call $switch so you dont have to query the object every time? In regards to Jan Dvorak, are there any performance differences?

Comment: @CristianRivera yes, that's exactly how the first example is written. There is no practical performance difference between `sign_in?0:1` and `+sign_in` AFAIK, but it's probably going to differ depending on the precise js engine that's running the code.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're using Bootstrap's Carousel? I've moved the two texts of the buttons to variables so that if you're using a minification tool (UglifyJs, Google's Closure Compiler etc), it'll help with minification.

I find using the index really reduces the readability of the code, so I've declared a variable `isSignUp`. This way, you reduce the cognitive load of the user reading the code. You don't have to remember which index is which after this declaration.

Since the `.item`s are already on the page, you can cache their lookup with `$carouselItems` and then find the `.active` one with `.index()`. A better approach could be to check for a specific class rather than index.

Shorter code isn't always the best approach. I find that the current answer is difficult to read.

```
$(function () {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel');
    var $carouselItems = $carousel.find('.carousel-inner .item');
    var $switch = $('#switch');
    var $header = $('#header');
    var $submit = $('#submit');

    var SIGN_IN = 'Sign In';
    var SIGN_UP = 'Sign Up';

    $carousel.on('slid', function() {
      var isSignIn = $carouselItems.index('.active') === 0;

      if (isSignIn) {
        $header.text(SIGN_IN);
        $switch.text(SIGN_UP);
        $submit.text(SIGN_IN).attr('form', 'sign_in');
      }
      else {
        $header.text(SIGN_UP);
        $switch.text(SIGN_IN);
        $submit.text(SIGN_UP).attr('form', 'sign_up');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this i am using your code for the index specifically with the other code from above